# ConnectException vs. IOException when wiFi is disabled?

Tags: android, exception, ioexception, connectexception

I tried connecting to an IP address (e.g. http://222.222.222.222:8080) and a URL (e.g. http://www.website.com) while my wiFi is disabled. I noticed that if I don't have a wiFi and I tried connecting to an IP address, it gives me a `ConnectException` error. On the other hand, if I don't have a wiFi and I tried connecting to a URL, it gives me an `IOException` error. Why am I receiving different `Exception` for the 2 cases when the only difference is I supplied an IP address for the first one and a URL for the other? Can someone enlighten me on this one? I am asking this for clarification.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using HttpUrlConnection, HttpClient or another class to connect to the URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting different errors because different steps are failing.

When you're trying to connect to port `80` of an IP address, it is a `connect(2)` system call that is failing. There are many different reasons why `connect(2)` could fail; you'll need to inspect the message from the exception to provide a good error message to the user.

When you're trying to connect to port `80` of a textual address, the libraries will first try to *resolve* the hostname into an IP address using `getaddrinfo(3)`. The name resolution may or may not fail based on having network access -- if you were trying to connect to `localhost`, for example, no network access is usually required, as the nameservice lookup can be handled entirely on the local device. Because the nameservice failure happens because you cannot contact a nameserver, it makes sense to give a different error message (and exception), even if the underlying *cause* is the same for a given set of tests. You might not be able to contact the nameservers for any variety of reasons. Again, you'll need to inspect the message from the exception to give a good error message to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I understand your explanation correctly, Android has different steps for connecting to an IP address and a textual address? Since the 2 has different steps, the error message are handled differently? Trying to connect to a textual address means you still have to connect to a nameserver to resolve the ip address. If it wasn't able to retrieve the ip address from the nameserver, a different error message is returned. A ConnectException is only returned if you are already trying to an IP address but fails to establish a connection?

Comment: It isn't specific to Android; it's generic across all devices and platforms that support the TCP/IP family of protocols. The details of the error messages change from platform to platform, but in general you can get the _protocol_-level error quite easily -- translating that to a human-friendly piece of advice such as "Your modem is unplugged" or "The network cable is backwards" or "The WiFi router is down" is immensely difficult.